# Progress bar when running Axios in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Could you help me to show a progress bar in Vue, I have my axios post and I make queries to the database with a lot of information and I would like to show the user the percentage of progress.

```
axios.post(url, data, {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + context.state.token}})
.then(async (response) => {
    resolve(response.data);
})
.catch(async(error) => {
    reject(error);
})
.finally(() => {
});
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. You should provide what you have tried so far and a bit more context: do you have a percentage returned by the api? Do you have to fake the percentage? What kind of data do you post in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the progress of the HTTP transfer like this

```js
axios.post(url, data, {
  headers: 
  {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + context.state.token
  },
  onUploadProgress: (event) =>
  {
    const percentUploaded = event.total ? Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total) : 0;
    // show or update the progressbar
  },
  onDownloadProgress: (event) =>
  {
    const percentDownloaded = event.total ? Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total) : 0;
    // show or update the progressbar
  }
})
.then(response => 
{
  // do something with response.data;
})
.catch(error => 
{
  // show an error alert;
})
.finally(() => 
{
  // nothing to do
});
```

The POST request will first upload the file and will update the upload progress, then it will download the response from the server and will update the download progress. The latter can be only measured reliably if the server sends `Content-Length` header.

It is difficult to make a combined progressbar because we do not know how many bytes will represent 100% on the combined progressbar until we receive the `Content-Length` header from the server and it is already too late when it comes. So you can simply show 2 progressbars - one for each direction of the HTTP transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you can do is to fake the values. You never know in beforehand what will be the size of the returned content. And the time elapsed until the Server begins returning anything is often times bigger than the time spent on actual downloading the response.

There are plenty of ways to take this behaviour, for example see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-progress-bar